# Visualising CPU usage in the form of Charts

Tags: c#, visual-studio

```
PerformanceCounter CPUCounter = new PerformanceCounter("Processor Information", "% Processor Time", "_Total");

chart1.Series["Usage %"].Points.AddY(CPUCounter);
```

The error message returned:

> System.ArgumentException: 'Series data points do not support values of
>   type System.Diagnostics.PerformanceCounter only values of these types
>   can be used: Double, Decimal, Single, int, long, uint, ulong, String,
>   DateTime, short, ushort.'

I am trying to get the CPU usage data visible on a line graph to show the usage history.

Comment: You're trying to add the performance counter itself, not the recorded performance values.

Answer (score 2):

The [PerformanceCounter](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.performancecounter(v=vs.110).aspx) class is only used to reference a specific NT performance counter component. Once you have an instance you either call `NextSample()` that would give you a [`CounterSample`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.countersample(v=vs.110).aspx) or you simply use the [`RawValue`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.performancecounter.rawvalue(v=vs.110).aspx) property, that will call NextSample if that wasn't done already.

I expect this to work for you, give or take rounding / scaling:

```
chart1.Series["Usage %"].Points.AddY(CPUCounter.RawValue); // Use RawValue property here
```

RawValue returns a long, and the exception message you got suggests long values are acceptable.